# What is difference in assigning hex or decimal value to uint16_t?

Tags: c

What is difference between these two types of assignments?

```
uint16_t x = 0x002f;
uint16_t y = 47;
```

Eventually both are 47, but is there any difference in the bits of both variables or something else.

Is it that hex one is better, if yes why so?

Comment: Hex and decimal are just 2 different ways of representing numbers. When working with bytes, hexadecimal is convenient to use as it is more compact.

Comment: There's no difference to the compiler. The choice is usually based on how useful one notation is to the human reader.

Comment: @binaryescape "hexadecimal is convenient to use as it is more compact" in terms of what?

Comment: A wider range of numbers can be represented with lesser symbols, compared to decimal.

Comment: @binaryescape that's not the reason why we represent numbers in hexadecimal. It's when that format is more *relevant*. Although your compactness idea *is* good when comparing binary or hexadecimal format, which the latter groups into 4 bits, and *readability* is also important.

Comment: It might be very helpful to realize that "eventually both are 0x2F" is just as valid as "eventually both are 47" here.

Comment: @Weather Vane indeed, but it is one reason to use hexadecimal notation, so when representing bytes, hex is more relevant than for example decimal notation in my opinion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is that there is no practical difference between the two initializations in the posted code:

```
uint16_t x = 0x002f;
uint16_t y = 47;
```

The values on the right are the same, they can be represented in a `uint16_t` type, and the result is that both `x` and `y` have the same value after initialization.

Sometimes it is convenient to prefer hexadecimal over decimal notation for the sake of readability. One typical example is that color values are often written as hexadecimal representations. RGB or RGBA color values are often represented by unsigned 32 bit integers. Such a color may be written as `0xCCDDEE` or `0xCCDDEEFF` where `CC` is the red value, `DD` is the green value, `EE` is the blue value, and `FF` is the alpha value. It is easier to understand the makeup of the color when seen as a hexadecimal representation versus the decimal representation of `3437096703`. It is challenging to see at a glance that the green value in this decimal number is `221`. Hexadecimal notation can also be convenient if you want to write a bitmask for extracting color values from such a color value, e.g., you could use `0x00FF0000` as a bitmask for extracting the green value (`0xDD`) from the RGBA value given by `0xCCDDEEFF` (or `3437096703`). And again it is easier to write down `0x00FF0000` for the bitmask than it is to write down the corresponding decimal representation `16711680`.

Even though the initializations in the OP posted code have the same effect, there is a subtle difference between these two lines of code.

### What Is the Type of an Integer Constant?

`47` is a *decimal constant*, while `0x002f` is a *hexadecimal constant*. Both of these are *integer constants*.

For decimal constants with no suffix the type is the first of `int`, `long int`, or `long long int` that can represent the value of the constant.

For hexadecimal (or octal, or binary) constants with no suffix the type is the first of `int`, `unsigned int`, `long int`, `unsigned long int`, `long long int`, or `unsigned long long int` that can represent the value of the constant. Note that binary integer constants were added in C23; previously they were supported by some implementations (implementations of earlier Standards were not required to follow the typing rules for binary integer constants specified in C23, but I suspect that they did).

***That is, unsuffixed decimal constants are always signed integer types, while unsuffixed binary, octal, and hexadecimal constants may be unsigned integer types.***<sup>1</sup>

Practically this has no consequences here for the posted initializations; what is important is that the *value* of the integer constant can be represented by the type on the left, i.e., `uint16_t` in this case. If this is not true then wrap-around conversion is specified by the C Standard for unsigned integer target types, while signed integer target types must either convert the value in an implementation-defined way, or an implementation-defined signal must be raised.

### Potential Problems with Unsigned Arithmetic

That integer constants may be unsigned isn't academic; there are pitfalls when unsigned arithmetic appears in unexpected places. Consider this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    long int x = 2147483647 - 0x80000000;  // 2147483647 - 2147483648
    long int y = 2147483647 - 2147483648;
    printf("x = %ld\n", x);
    printf("y = %ld\n", y);
}
```

Note that the behavior here is not undefined; it is well-defined by the C Standard. Yet the rules of integer conversion can catch the unwary and even experienced programmers off-guard. Here is the output of the program on my machine:

```
$ ./a.out 
x = 4294967295
y = -1
```

Since the integer constants `0x80000000` and `2147483648` have the same value, one might expect that the results of printing `x` and `y` above would be the same. But `0x80000000` is an `unsigned int` on my machine (where `INT_MAX` is 0x7FFFFFFF or 2147483647, hence an `int` can't represent 0x80000000 here), while `2147483648` is a `long int`. These both have the same *value* but different *types*. The value of the decimal constant `2147483647` in the above expressions, which is an `int` in both cases since this value can be represented by an `int` on my machine.

The usual arithmetic conversions are applied to the expressions so that the type of the value 2147483647 is converted to `unsigned int` in the expression with the hexadecimal constant. On the other hand, the type of the value 2147483647 is converted to `long int` in the expression with the decimal constant.

Due to the wrapping nature of unsigned arithmetic, the subtraction of the *unsigned* values (2147483647 - 2147483648) gives an unsigned result of 4294967295 which is assigned to `x` (this is `UINT_MAX` on my machine).

But the subtraction of the *signed* values (2147483647 - 2147483648) gives a signed result of -1 which is assigned to `y`.

The moral of this story is that it is probably best to use hexadecimal (or octal, or binary) constants with care. They can serve the interest of clarity, e.g., when describing bit patterns or color codes, but they can be tricky when used in expressions.

<sup>1</sup> *If the value of the integer constant cannot be represented by one of it's listed types, an extended integer type may be applied here if a suitable type is available. If no such type is available there is a constraint violation and the implementation must issue a diagnostic message.*

Comment: Interesting. Would this be different if their second example was `uint16_t y = 47u;`?

Comment: @pmacfarlane -- with `uint16_t y = 47u` the integer constant would have type `unsigned int`, where with `uint16_t y = 47` the integer constant would have type `int`. But beyond that there is no difference AFAIK. The `u` suffix forces unsigned constants so that both decimal and binary/octal/hexadecimal constants obey the same type rules. There might be problems in arithmetic expressions using integer constants where unsigned conversions could lead to unexpected results.

Comment: @pmacfarlane -- I have added an example of where problems may occur when using potentially unsigned integer constants.

Comment: @pmacfarlane The constant would have a different type (`unsigned`), but the result would be the same since fourty seven can be represented by a `uint16_t`.

Answer (score 7):

Those are just two different ways of expressing the same number. The value in the variable will be identical either way.

The reason you use decimal vs. hexadecimal (or octal, which is also supported) is for the sake of a person reading the code.

For example, if you look up the address of some hardware on a machine, chances are pretty good that it'll be expressed in hex or octal (hex tend to be popular recently, octal used to be). So, if the datasheet says port X is at address 0x0378, most code that needs to talk to that port is likely to use 0x0378, rather than 888, even though they're equivalent (back in the MS-DOS days, I wrote a fair number of programs that talked to port 0x378--but it wasn't until today, writing this answer I became aware that was equivalent to 888 decimal). Other experienced MS-DOS programmers (and quite a few non-programmers as well) would have recognized `0x378` as "parallel port" almost without thinking about it, but probably would not have recognized `888` at all.

For another example, if you're dealing with UNIX-style file permissions, you have read, write and execute permissions for owner, group, and world. So you have three groups of three bits apiece. Since one octal digit represents three bits, many people find it fairly natural to represent file permissions as octal numbers. So, if you use `ls -l` to display file permissions, it'll normally show them in octal, and if you use `chmod` to change them, you can enter them in octal (though you can also do something like `chmod +x foo` to mar `foo` as executable). So, if you're going to do the equivalent of `chmod` inside a program, many people find it natural to use octal there as well.

For one last example, consider color numbers. In a typical color, I have 8 bits each for the amount of red, green, and blue in a result. So, the RGB color numbers for pure red, pure green, and pure blue are `0xff0000`, `0x00ff00` and `0x0000ff` respectively. And at a simple level, I can mix things by hand as well. Pure yellow means "no blue", so that's `0xffff00`. Pink means red with less green and blue (but about equal to each other), so something like `0xff9f9f`. Since I have two digits apiece for each component of the color, these are pretty easy to manipulate by hand. But if I try to do it in decimal, it's all kind of a giant jumble of meaningless digits.

Answer (score 5):

`0x002f` and `47` are two ways of specifying the `int` forty-seven. These two variables will be initialized with exactly the same value, forty-seven.

Aside from the fact that they were both initialized from exactly the same `int`, there's only one bit pattern that represents forty-seven for an integer of a given size. There is no difference between the value of the two variables.

The choice of which to use will be based on which is deemed more readable in a specific situation. It would make more sense to use a decimal literal for a number of days, while it would make more sense to use hex for a bit mask.

Answer (score 0):

Your coded numeric representations are parsed to the specific engineered value space in use by the compiler.  Both representations express the same value to the compiler, which remains agnostic to the format you choose.

Compressing your code to always use decimal risks obscuring the meaning of how the value is represented in a particular numerical base. we want our code to be sufficiently high-level so as to retain as much human-readability as possible.

As mentioned above in certain instances you want to prefer to keep a value in base 16 rather than performing a manual calculation into decimal, for example the hexadecimal representation of RGB colors.

I will also mention the usefulness extends to *octal* numbers (base 8).  See, for example, https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/File-system_permissions#Numeric_notation in which POSIX file permission levels can be represented as a convenient three-digit octal number, which retain the positional argumentation of the three permission levels, world, group, and owner. Although many scientists prefer the easily memorized symbolic representation, the three digit octal codes are also widely understood as part of the natural language of that system.